# Reset button and clear the board

Tags: javascript, function, button, tic-tac-toe

I finally made my game work... The only problem is when I reset the page clicking on my reset button it would yes clear the board but It won't allow me to play any longer..How can I solve this problem?

HTML

```
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<div id="message"> </div>

<button id="reset" > Reset</button>
<div class="console">

   <div id="firstRow">
      <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
   </div>


   <div class="secondRow">
      <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box5" class="box"> </div>
      <div id="box6" class="box"> </div>
   </div>


   <div class="thirdRow">
      <div id="box7" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box8" class="box"> </div>
      <div id="box9" class="box"> </div>
   </div>

</div>

  JAVASCRIPT

 var turn = "X";
 var  winner = null; // to change player's turnn at the begin


  var nextMove = function(box) {
    if(winner !== null){
    setMessage(winner +" already won the game");
    clearBox();
   }
    else if(box.innerHTML === ""){
       box.innerHTML = turn;
       switchTurn();
     }

    else {
      setMessage("Choose another box.");

     }
  }

   var startGame = function() {
   for (var i =1; i <= 9; i++) { //clears all my boxes
   clearBox(i);
   }

  setMessage(turn + " gets to start.");
  } 

  var setMessage = function(msg) {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
  }   



      function switchTurn() {

         if(checkWinner(turn)) {
           setMessage("Congratulations, " + turn + " wins!");
           winner = turn; // whoever wins is gonna start the game
         }

         else if(turn === "X") {
           turn = "O";
           setMessage("It's " + turn + " turn.");
          }

         else {
            turn = "X";
            setMessage("Its " + turn + " turn.");

           }

         }

    function checkWinner(move) {
      var result = false;
      if( checkRow(1, 2, 3, move) ||
          checkRow(4, 5, 6, move) ||
          checkRow(7, 8, 9, move) ||
          checkRow(1, 4, 7, move) ||
          checkRow(2, 5, 8, move) ||
          checkRow(3, 6, 9, move) ||
          checkRow(1, 5, 9, move) ||
          checkRow(3, 5, 7, move)) {

        result = true;
      }

      return result;

    }

    function checkRow(a, b, c, move) {
      var result = false;
      if(getBox(a) === move && getBox(b) === move && getBox(c) === move) {
        result = true;
      }

      return result;
    }

    function getBox(number) {
      return document.getElementById("box" + number).innerHTML;

    }

    function clearBox(number) {
      return document.getElementById("box" + number).innerHTML = "";
    }


 var btnReset = document.getElementById('reset');

  btnReset.addEventListener('click', function() {
      startGame();

   });

 var consoleDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("console")[0];

  consoleDiv.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // event.target === the box to go in
   nextMove(event.target);
   var hasWon = checkWinner();


});

 startGame();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `clearBox();` from your nextMove function and add `winner = null;` to your `btnReset.addEventListener('click', function() {` function.

Once the player won, winner was never set back to null therefore there was always a winner and since you check `winner !== null`, below that you would call the `clearBox()` which would then call the function without the required parameter and it would break your program.